# Get layout constraints for a component in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, layout, constraints, miglayout

Below is a mock up of code that I've been working on.

```
public class Pane {

    private final JPanel pane;
    private JPanel namePanel;
    private final JTextField panIdField;

    public Pane() {
        pane = new JPanel();
        pane.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[][grow]", "[][][][][]"));

        namePanel = new JPanel();
        pane.add(namePanel, "cell 1 1,growx");

        panIdField = new JTextField();
        pane.add(panIdField, "cell 1 2,growx");
        panIdField.setColumns(10);

    }

    public void replaceNameField(JPanel newNamePanel) {
        this.namePanel = newNamePanel;
        // Object constraintsForNamePanel = 
        pane.remove(namePanel);
        pane.add(newNamePanel, constraintsForNamePanel);
    }

}
```

In Container there's method

```
public void add(Component comp, Object constraints)
```

Is there any way that we can programatically get the `constraints` that we set, like `getConstraints(...)` so that we can use it for later use?

In my code, I want to use it to replace a old component with a new one at the same place.

What do I have to do after

```
 Object constraintsForNamePanel =
```

to get the constraints for `namePanel`.

Currently, I'm using

```
pane.add(newNamePanel, "cell 1 1,growx");
```

It is working but the problem is I'm using `WindowsBuilder` for UI and my UI is like to change when I add new components to the `pane` and I don't want to copy and paste the constraints.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got the solution, I had to do following.

```
public void replaceNameField(JPanel newNamePanel) {
     MigLayout layout = (MigLayout) pane.getLayout();
     Object constraintsForNamePanel = layout.getComponentConstraints(this.namePanel);
     pane.remove(this.namePanel);

      this.namePanel = newNamePanel;
      pane.add(newNamePanel, constraintsForNamePanel);
    }
```

Comment: As far as I can see, it doesn't even require to remove the component. Just re-adding the same component with new constraints should replace the existing one without createing a new one.